# Diodes Problem - Forward or Reverse Bias

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

[image]

Hi, I am stuck on the solution to this problem. I understand that the second LED is in reverse bias due to its polarity, however, I do not understand how I can be sure LED1 is in forward bias. How can you actually be sure that the 4.5V source results in a resulting voltage of greater than 2V before it reaches the LED. How can you determine the voltage drop across the 75 ohm resistor?

It helped me to see that the resistor can be either on top of or below the diode, but, that does not convince me that the forward voltage of the diode will be more than 2V, since it can still be placed below the resistor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I do not understand how I can be sure LED1 is in forward bias. How can
> you actually be sure that the 4.5V source results in a resulting
> voltage of greater than 2V before it reaches the LED*

You consider scenarios: -

If LED1 isn't conducting then, there must be less than 2 volts across it. That means there must be some voltage across the 75 Ω resistor. If there is some voltage across the 75 Ω resistor there must be current flowing and, that current must be flowing through LED1 hence, this scenario is false and the LED must be conducting and have 2 volts across it.

> *How can you determine the voltage drop across the 75 ohm resistor?*

With 2 volts across the LED (one side of the 75 Ω resistor) and 4.5 volts on the other side of the resistor, there has to be 2.5 volts across the resistor. This means the resistor current is 2.5/75 = 33.333 mA.

Answer (score 1):

If diode voltage is less than 2V, current through the resistor and diode will be very small. So, the resistor drop will be close to 0V. KVL will not get satisfied. So, the diode voltage will have to become 2V first. The current will then increase and increase the resistor voltage until the resistor voltage becomes 4.5V-2V = 2.5V